# Why do I keep getting “There is no SSL certificate configured for this domain.” even other people see my web page?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I recently created a domain and put some file on it, on:

```
https://gitareradovic.com/
https://www.gitareradovic.com/
```

either one should be working.

However, I always get the message "There is no SSL certificate configured for this domain."

But I seem to be the only one who is not able to see the website. On the server, currently there is only one file, a PHP file, with some random text "testiranje" on it. I found out that some people can see it, however, I cannot proceed with development on it, because I can't access it, I cannot see the page. I tried clearing cache, on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, always getting the same outcome. I tried browsers on my iPhone too. All of my browsers are on the same wifi network (or cable network for that matter, since I tried it also on desktop).

Some other people (the staff rom the hosting server that I installed the file on) and some other people, are actually able to see the text "testiranje", but not me. Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Comment: This looks like a problem with your local network. a) check if the problem still occurs if you switch to mobile network on the smart phone b) check which IP address is returned for the domain in your network, it should be 198.54.115.169 c) reboot your router since there might be some DNS caching going on.

Comment: Looks like a WordPress installation to me. Are you still having a problem?

Comment: Meanwhile I managed through another computer, to install wordpress, yes. I still have the issue, however. From my computer I cannot access anything.

Comment: I will try and restart modem on my home network, I am sure on other networks there are no issues, since everyone else can see it normally....

Answer (score 0):

Kindly contact your hosting service provider. your local system IP blocked by the server. Due to this issue, only one person is not able to see your website.